# Can I make nice Kotlin extension function?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Here is my code

```
  theme?.let {
  ....
    titleText.setTextColor(it.pTextColor)
    contentText.setTextColor(it.pTextColor)
  }
}
```

and the usage of this extension is here
`cardView.setTheme(theme)`

How can I have this `cardView.theme = theme`

Comment: I don't get your question. You haven't posted the definition of this extension function `cardView.setTheme(theme)` and `cardView.theme = theme` that would be an extension property not a function, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks @donfuxx yes I forgot about extension properties 
it is what I want to do , but as I understand from the doc you posted initializers are not allowed for extension properties, so I can't do what I wanted to do yes?

Answer (score 2):

you can write extension function:

```
fun CardView.setTheme(theme: Theme) {
    val titleText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
    val contentText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content)
    titleText.setTextColor(theme.pTextColor)
    contentText.setTextColor(theme.pTextColor)
}
```

or extension property:

```
var CardView.theme: Theme?
    get() = null
    set(value) {
        value ?: return
        val titleText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
        val contentText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content)
        titleText.setTextColor(value.pTextColor)
        contentText.setTextColor(value.pTextColor)
    }
```

Comment: Extension function version works but I would like to use the extension property
and when I use it says property must be initialized , ?

Comment: sorry, don't get your question. Extension property is just syntactic sugar for static function. You don't have to initialize it

Comment: but it doesn't compile.